# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'email'

Tags: python

Any idea how can this error be solved? I took the program from this [link](https://github.com/gjreda/craigslist-checker/blob/master/craigslist.py) and it works correctly for them.

```
def send_text(phone_number, msg):
    fromaddr = "Craigslist Checker"
    toaddrs = phone_number + "@txt.att.net"
    msg = ("From: {0}\r\nTo: {1}\r\n\r\n{2}").format(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(config.email['email'], config.email['password'])
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()
```

here's the error:

```
There are new results - sending text message to 2014-09-06 01:58:09
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t1.py", line 85, in <module>
    send_text(PHONE_NUMBER, message)
  File "t1.py", line 60, in send_text
    server.login(config.email['email'], config.email['password'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'email'
```

Comment: `print vars(config)` to see its attributes

Comment: This is a program I am using from a website and I think it should work.

Comment: Maybe config name is a dict

Comment: @alfasin here's the link https://github.com/gjreda/craigslist-checker/blob/master/craigslist.py

Comment: I can see that, did you import the whole project ? did you setup: https://github.com/gjreda/craigslist-checker/blob/master/config.py ?

Comment: @alfasin thank you so much. That fixed that problem. I am a newbie

Comment: @MonaJalal not a problem ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, do you a python novice, right? The setup should be:

```
~$ wget https://github.com/gjreda/craigslist-checker/archive/master.zip
~$ cd craigslist-checker-master
~$ pip install -r requirements.txt
~$ echo "email={'username':'mail@gmail.com', 'password':'youpass'}" > config.py 
~$ python ./craigslist.py
```